# How to convert certain items from a long list to data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a list which is 4500 elements long. Each list is of length 7. Will it be possible to extract certain items from each list and convert to a data frame. Below is an example

```
List1 <- list(Name = "Peter" , Age = 25 , State = "Texas" , Occupation = "Analyst1" , Salary =5000)

List2 <- list(Name = "Susan" , Age = 30 , State = "New York" , Occupation = "Analyst11" , Salary =7000)

List3 <- list(Name = "John" , Age = 35 , State = "New Jersey" , Occupation = "Manager" , Salary =10000)
List4 <- list(Name = "Sam" , Age = 30 , State = "Florida" , Occupation = "Analyst1" , Salary =5000)
List5 <- list(Name = "Judy" , Age = 30 , State = "California" , Occupation = "Analyst11" , Salary =7000)
FinalList <- list(List1 , List2, List3 , List4 , List5)
```

I would like to create a data frame with columns Name, Age and Salary. I tried using do.call like

```
 FinalResult <- do.call(rbind ,FinalList[][-c(3,4)] )
```

Which is creating a dataframe as shown below:

```
 #     name    Age State        Occupation  Salary
 #[1,] "Peter" 25  "Texas"      "Analyst1"  5000  
 #[2,] "Sam"   30  "Florida"    "Analyst1"  5000  
 #[3,] "Judy"  30  "California" "Analyst11" 7000
```

But what I would like to create is

```
 #         name    Age   Salary
 #[1,]    "Peter"  25    5000  
 #[2,]    "Susan"  30    7000  
 #[3,]    "John"   35    10000 
 #[4,]    "Sam"    30    5000  
 #[5,]    "Judy"   30    7000
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you were trying to do was :

```
do.call(rbind ,FinalList)[, -c(3, 4)]
#If needed as dataframe
#do.call(rbind.data.frame,FinalList)[, -c(3, 4)]
```

Or probably simpler using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(FinalList) %>% select(-(3:4))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(FinalList)[, -c(3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `unnest_wider`

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col = FinalList) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(col)) %>%
    dplyr::select(-c(3:4))
```